# Not able to add values properly to HashMap in android

Tags: java, android, arraylist, hashmap

I am using `Hashmap<String, ArrayList<String>>` in my code. I have different posts. post1 has 8 comments, post2 has 3 comments, post3 has 4 comments.

I am adding values to hashmap as shown below:

```
HashMap.put(postId, commentList);
```

I am reading all the comments of every post through for loop. Totally there are 5 posts. I am getting HashMap of size 5. but my problem is the arraylist size is same for all hashmap values. Instead the arraylist value for 1st value of HashMap should be 8, arraylist value of second hashmap should be 3 etc..

Please let me know what mistake am I doing. My code looks as shown below:

```
 JSONArray conversationArray = c.getJSONArray("conversation");

for (int i2 = 0; i2 < conversationArray.length(); i2++) {

JSONObject conversationArray1 = conversationArray.getJSONObject(i2);
contentConversation = conversationArray1.getString("content");
commenterName = conversationArray1.getString("commenterName");
postIdForComments = conversationArray1.getString("postId");

commentDescription.add(contentConversation);
commentUserName.add(commenterName);

commentDescriptionHashMap.put(postIdForComments, commentDescription);
commentUserNameHashMap.put(postIdForComments, commentUserName);

     }
```

My Json Object:

```
"conversation": [
        {
          "_id": "568525b97113a4b417db2eb0",
          "content": "kl;,",
          "commenterId": "56332edfad441746cbd15000",
          "commenterName": "yashas cl",
          "commenterPhotos": "https://toadfiles.s3.amazonaws.com/56332edfad441746cbd15000_1450158467841images.jpg",
          "postId": "568520a01931912c03eb1a16",
          "lastDateUpdated": "2015-12-31T12:55:21.151Z",
          "dateCreated": "2015-12-31T12:55:21.151Z",
          "isDeleted": false,
          "__v": 0,
          "against": [],
          "for": [],
          "commenterUserName": [
            "yashas"
          ]
        }
```

I have tried clearing Arraylists after completion of for loop. When I clear arraylists the value of hashmap list will become zero. I am struggling a lot to figure out what has happended. Please give me suggestions for coming out of this issue.

Comment: There's a *lot* of (badly formatted) code there. Please take the time to reduce this to a [mcve]. I note that `commentAgreeCountHashMap.put(postIdForComments, commentDisAgreeCount);` looks incorrect to start with, mind you...

Comment: Along with proper formatting add only minimum required code which can be more readable.

Comment: The code still looks very badly formatted to me, and still doesn't look like a minimal example.

Comment: @ParagKadam I have formatted the code. I have removed few lines of code which were not needed. Please check.

Comment: @JonSkeet Please check now.

Comment: Your code is in bad shape. Why is there so much space in between the lines? Also there is still a lot of extra code there.

Comment: @ParagKadam please check now

Comment: How does you json object look like , can you post it.

Comment: @ParagKadam Updated. I don think there is need for to post JSON object . I am getting the values properly. Any how, i have updated it.

Comment: Your code is *still* badly formatted - and *still* isn't a short but complete example. The indentation is off, and you're still using loads of variables whose declaration and initialization you've never shown us. Please read http://tinyurl.com/stack-hints before you next ask a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the issue. I should initialize the arraylist every time before updating the hashmap. Before adding the value second time I should initialize the arraylist as

```
ArrayList<String> = new ArrayList<String>.
```

I was doing this only one time.This was the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

Create a `Comment` class,

```
class Comment
{
  String commentId,content,commentorId,commenterName,postId; //You can add more, depends on your requirement
}

Set<String> postIdSet;
JSONArray conversationArray = c.getJSONArray("conversation");

for (int j = 0; j < conversationArray.length(); j++) {

JSONObject comment = conversationArray.getJSONObject(j);
String postIdForComments = comment.getString("postId");
postIdSet = new HashSet<String>();
postIdSet.add(postIdForComments);

     }
for (int j = 0; j < conversationArray.length(); j++) {
      List<Comment> commentList = new ArrayList<Comment>();
      Comment comment = new Comment();
      JSONObject comment = conversationArray.getJSONObject(j);
      comment.commentId = comment.getString("_id");
      comment.content = comment.getString("content"); 
      comment.commentorId = comment.getString("commentorId");
      comment.commentorName = comment.getString("commentorName");
      comment.postId = comment.getString("postId");
      commentList.add(comment);
 }

   ArrayList<HashMap<String,ArrayList<Comment>>> arrayListOfHashmap = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,ArrayList<Comment>>>();
  for(j=0;j<postIdSet.size();j++)
  {
   ArrayList<Comment> cList;
   for(i =0 ;i<commentList.size();i++)
   {
      if(postIdSet.get(i).equals(commentList.get(i).postId))
      {
         cList = new ArrayList<Comment>();
         cList.add(commentList.get(i));    

      }
   }
    HashMap<String,ArrayList<Comment>> tempMap = new HashMap<String,ArrayList<Comment>>();
    tempMap.put(postIdSet.get(i),cList);
    arrayListOfHashmap.add(temp);  
  }

  Log.e("Map",arrayListOfHashmap);
```

There could be a lot of typos since I did not type it in the editor, but you should be able to fix it.

Comment: I have tried this even then I don get different array list sizes for different posts

Comment: What does one entity of the `conversation` JSON array represent? I guess it represents a single comment. Right?

Comment: Its a loop of comments for a particular post. If a post has 8 comments that for loop, loops 8 times.

Comment: is this the entire json object or is there more? if this is the entire json object then is your `_id` value uniqe for each post?

Comment: yes _id object is unique for each post, this is the json object of comments part. Entire json object is too big to post it. The _id value of post and postId of conversation json object both are same.

Comment: Ok I think i got what is wrong ,will soon update my answer.

Comment: Ok Thanks. every time when I add value to hashmap, the previous arraylist size is getting changed.